# Dúvida: Intersecção entre Databases diferentes

Tags: php

Esse POST é mais uma dúvida do que realmente um problema, eu tenho o seguinte cenário:

Duas base de dados diferentes, DB2 e PSQL, elas contém registros de coletas de monitoramenro, eu preciso criar uma intersecção entre elas (DB2xPSQL) em PHP. Eu realizo o select nas databases, e salvo em arrays os resultados.

**Exemplo:** `$get_sql[] = odbc_result($result, "COLUMNNAME")`

O que eu preciso fazer é comparar a coluna **HOSTNAME** que contém nas duas base de dados e filtrar o que existe de igual e diferente entre elas, gerando uma tabela no **FRONT-END**, estou utilizando a função nativa do PHP `array_intersect()` para pegar o que existe de igual e `array_diff()` para pegar o que existe de diferente entre elas.
Após receber o que existe de igual em um novo array, eu passo esse array dentro de um **SELECT** com clausúla **WHERE** onde o valor dela é o array de intersecção, assim ela me retorna a linha do valor de intersecção com todos os dados, e não somente o campo de **HOSTNAME**, eu preciso gerar isso de forma mais eficaz, pois estou falando de cerca de 10 mil registros em cada base de dados, e está forma está criando um sobrecarregamento ao banco de dados. Como vocês fariam essa intersecção?

*A pergunta não está no escopo do site porém acredito que possa ajudar alguém futuramente com o mesmo cenário, por isso irei manter a mesma publicada!*

Comment: Por acaso um foreign-data wrapper não atenderia a suas necessidades resolvendo no próprio SGBD sem ter que fazer no php?

Comment: Não tinha pensado nisso, vou me interar mais sobre, obrigado pela dica!